# Reputation widget not working

Tags: bug, android-app

When trying to place the rep widget on the homescreen, it initially says you need to login.

But I'm already logged in. 
So I reopened the app, tried to place the widget and then I got an illegalStateException.

The launcher I'm using is Google Now launcher.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5X
- OS Version: 7.0 (3239497)